# net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.jtdsresultset@1245 gives output for select itemname from oitm where itemcode='dcs1515' on android

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, android-studio

I had developed an android app to connect with MS-sql database it is connected but it does not get correct result it gives

net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.jtdsresultset@1245 
as result for select itemname from oitm where itemcode='dcs1515'

Please help me to solve this issue. I am using android studio-3.1.0 and ms-sql 2008. I connected android with db using jtds-1.3.1.jar for jdbc connection

```
class Disp extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
                connect con = new connect();
                String k=null;
                ct = con.connectionclass();
                if (ct == null){
                   k="Check Internet";

                    }
                else{
                    try {
                        String st = "select itemname from oitm where itemcode='dcs1515'";
                        Statement smt = ct.createStatement();

                            ResultSet resultSet = smt.executeQuery(st);
                            if(resultSet.next())
                            {
                                k = resultSet.toString();//"success ";//+resultSet+" deleted";


                            }
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            k=e.getMessage();

                        }


                }



                return k;
            }
        }
    }
```

connection class is

```
 public class connect {
        String ip = "192.167.0.7";
        String db = "RCCLive";
        String un = "artika";
        String pass = "Acm@157";
        public Connection connectionclass()
        {
            {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                Connection connection = null;
                String ConnectionURL = null;
                try
                {
                    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
                    ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";" + db + ";user=" + un+ ";password=" + pass + ";";
                    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
                }
                catch (SQLException se)
                {
                    Log.e("error here 1 : ", se.getMessage());
                }
                catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
                {
                    Log.e("error here 2 : ", e.getMessage());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("error here 3 : ", e.getMessage());
                }
                return connection;
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
k = resultSet.toString();
```

This should be

```
k = resultSet.getString(1);
```

You cannot just take the `String` value of the `ResultSet`, you must retrieve the first column of the `ResultSet`, which is what `getString(1)` does.

Comment: But when I try to insert data I can't able to insert

Comment: Ask a separate question and be sure to explain clearly what you mean by "can't insert".

Comment: I cant post another question I have to wait for 90 min

Comment: Can you send me your mail id

Comment: Then wait 90 minutes.  Take those 90 minutes to prepare the question in a text editor and study the relevant documentation to see if you can figure it out on your own.

Comment: please help me its urgent ,help me to solve these issues

Comment: Sorry, we don't do "urgent" here, and we do not share email addresses.

Comment: I just altered above codding as

Comment: String st = "delete ce where id=4650'";
                        Statement smt = ct.createStatement();

                            int resultSet = smt.executeUpdate(st);
                            if(resultSet!=0)
                            {
                                k = "success";
                            }